# Mountain Lion's Migration Assistant not seeing USB hard drive

Tags: macos, restore

I just replaced a hard drive in a MacBook Pro for a bigger one. I connected the previous one using a SATA/USB adaptor and I was able to mount it and see the files in it. Both the old and the new hard drive have FileVault enabled.

When I try to transfer the data using Migration Assistant it stays *looking* and it never shows the old hard drive as an option. I selected to restore from a back up or other drive.

Any ideas what might be going on or how to get more information?

Answer (score 0):

What did you have to do to mount the hard drive via the SATA/USB adaptor when you tested it?

I helped a relative with a similar problem recently, and it turned out her external hard drive enclosure's built-in SATA/USB adaptor had a proprietary password protection mechanism (it was a WD My Book) that required proprietary software be installed on the Mac that needed to unlock/access it. Once she disabled that password mechanism on her external hard drive, Migration Assistant on her new Mac was able to access it.

[Even if this is not the solution for you, I'll probably leave this Answer here in case it helps others who come here seeking answers to similar questions.]

Comment: I connected the drive to a USB/SATA adaptor, turned it on, plugged it and then entered the FileVault password when prompted. No proprietary stuff beyond Apple's here.